# Select from a same table columns with same date but different foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, selection

I have the following table

table name: `hydroraw`

```
idhydroraw|idstndb|dates|dist_raw|lvl_m

1|1|2011-12-14 14:20|2.3|4.5

2|1|2011-12-14 14:30|2.4|4.3

1|2|2011-12-14 14:20|6  |9

2|2|2011-12-14 14:30|8  |10
```

...etc

I trying select `dist_raw` and `lvl_m` `where idstndb =1 and idstndb=2` but for same dates and to produce something like this:

```
2011-12-14 14:20|2.3|4.5|6 | 9

2011-12-14 14:30|2.4|4.3|8 | 10
```

I am new to sql and **I would like to ask for some hints - not the solution**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for some light to find answers. Please check this link as well. It clearly explains the [difference between each JOIN type used in SQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-full-join-in-mys)

If you are getting into SQL, the most important thing is to know about these joins as much as your entity and refrential integrity relationships. :)

On a latter note, There doesn't seem to have a primary key in your above table anyway... Anyway good luck. Let us know if you need the answer. Here is a tool that you can use only for quicker table, sql query testing as well.

- [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the concept of [INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Then look at '[SELF JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)'.